# Update registry on remote machine

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I am writing an Inno Setup script and I need to add a registry key on remote machine. I am not able to achieve this using Inno setup.

I tried the following code but it does not work.

```
Exec('cmd.exe', 'reg add \\REMOTEPC\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v test /t REG_SZ /d C:\Support\Test.exe /f', '',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

I looked at `RegWriteStringValue` as well.

Comment: That's what you cannot do in Inno Setup natively. Built-in registry functions work on local machine only. So [`the first approach`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742162.aspx) is the way to go. First off, try to execute the command line in command prompt and see if it works, or what it returns. Once you get it working, remove executing of the command prompt (I don't know who brought this to Inno Setup, but it's meaningless in 99% of use cases; you might be missing `/C` here, but do not do that). Execute directly `reg`.

Comment: However, it might be possible (and better for processing the result) to do that with a few WinAPI functions (`RegConnectRegistry` and others).

Comment: I tried this to add registry on my local machine. `Exec('reg', 'add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v Status /t REG_SZ /d FULL /f', '',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);` The ResultCode is 0. But still no registry added.

Comment: Because you missed the remote machine prefix ? Still, first try to run that command in command prompt before you move it to the Inno Setup script. Better for this will be the WinAPI way though.

Comment: I am trying to add on local machine only this time. If it works then I will try for remote. In command prompt it works fine.

Comment: If you have 64-bit system, are you sure you are checking the correct registry view ? If you'd run 64-bit command prompt and check that value through the 64-bit regedit, you should not be mistaken though.

Comment: You are right TLama. It is updating the registry in Wow6432Node. How should I force it on 64 bit machine to update in right place?

Comment: I don't know, I can't remember if I ever used that tool. But I would expect that 64-bit command prompt will redirect to the 64-bit view. But anyway, quite worse will be running your setup on 32-bit machine updating 64-bit registry keys of the remote machine (see e.g. [`this article`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948698/en-us)). But that's quite out of scope of this question. [have to go now...]

Comment: Reg key is added to Wow6432Node probably because your Setup runs as 32bit application. Try running it in 64bit mode and see if the result will be as expected.